# Custom animation for ExpandableListView Child

Tags: android, animation, parent-child, expandablelistview, slide

I wanna use a custom animation (slide down/up) for childs in an ExpandableListView. So if I click on element #2, I want the child of parent element #2 to expand using the animation. And withdraw / close, when I click the parent again.

However, I do have problems directing the animation at the child itself. The closest I can get, is to animate the parent, by using "myListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).setAnimation(slide_down);" as seen below.
When I use this pierce of code and I click element x, then element x will makes an animation - But it's the child who should make the animation, not the clicked parent.

My code in MainActivity, where "myAdapter" is the adapter and "myListView" is the ExpandableListView:

```
    ExpandableListAdapter myAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(context, arrRO);
    final ExpandableListView myListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.reminderlistView);
    myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    myListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            if (myListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                //Need to implement collapsing animation as well
                myListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            } else {
                boolean autoScrollToExpandedGroup = false;
                myListView.expandGroup(groupPosition, autoScrollToExpandedGroup);
                setupLayoutAnimation(groupPosition);
                //
            }
            //telling the listView we have handled the group click, and don't want the default actions.
            return true;
        }

        private void setupLayoutAnimation(int groupPosition) {

            Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);

            myListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).setAnimation(slide_down);

            //myListView.setAnimation(slide_down);

        }
```

I also included the "myListView.setAnimation(slide_down);", but if I use that and click on an element, every single displayed element (parents + children) make this little animation, and I only want it for the child.

There will always only be 1 child, for every parent, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

ExpandableListView is not very flexible. You are probably better off creating a custom view where you can control how the children of a group are displayed when the group is clicked.

There is a bit more work to get your custom view in place, but it'll aford you much more flexibility that an ExpandableListView can.

You'll need 2 new views, a Parent view, and a child view. The Parent view will inherit from one of the ViewGroups (use LinearLayout or FrameLayout as you have a single child), while the childView will be based on what you want to display, it could be a TextView or some ViewGroup with a few child views. When you detect a click on the Parent, you would animate the child it contains, and you could pass that click event up the chain using an interface if needed.